# Does a PostgreSQL composite index (A, B, C) also cover queries that use (A,B) and (B,A)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know queries that filter on A only can use the index (A,B,C), but queries that filter on B or C cannot.

What about queries that filter on both A and B but in no particular order (i.e, the WHERE clause lists either A or B first)? Can they make use of the index in either case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the comparisons does not matter.  So if you have equality conditions, then:

```
where a = ? and b = ?
```

can optimally use indexes on `(a, b)` and on `(b, a)`.  Similarly:

```
where b = ? and a = ?
```

can optimally use both those indexes as well.

Note:  This is true for equality conditions.  The use of indexes is a bit different for other types of comparisons.

Comment: And in my case, I have an extra "C" in the index (A,B,C), this still holds true for A and B, right?